# C# - Opening multiple cmd windows inside a C# winForm application

Tags: c#, python, cmd

I use C# to make a GUI for a python application. I should run the python app in a cmd window, because it has outputs in it to show to user.

I actually did that successfully using this snippet:

```
Process runProg = new Process();
runProg.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c py " +botFilePath +" --config_path=" + configFilePath + " --config_index=username_" + index.ToString();
runProg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
runProg.Start();
pIds[index] = System.Convert.ToInt32(runProg.Id.ToString());
```

BUT, If I open 3 process with this code, it will work just fine but after a while it will close the 2 of them and just keep running on one of them. so it will close 2 cmd and just keeps the last one that I opened.

how can I keep the 3 of the cmd windows open and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

`runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c py " +botFilePath +" --config_path=" + configFilePath + " --config_index=username_" + index.ToString();`

/C carries out the command and then terminates

/K carries out the command but remains

Try using /K instead:

`runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/K py " +botFilePath +" --config_path=" + configFilePath + " --config_index=username_" + index.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Starting `cmd` with option /k instead of /c?

> /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains